# Spring externalize configuration yml

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to configure the spring-boot application with `yml` and `properties`. I might have made mistakes at multiple places :)

I run my application as below with following contents :

```
java -jar /opt/elast-search-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=. --spring.config.name=elast.properties,ere.yml
```

My YAML file looks like :

```
log:
  count: 1
  searchText: someText
  services:
    - um
    - sa
  minutesTime: 1

  count: 2
  searchText: someMoreText
  services:
    - um2
    - sa2
  minutesTime: 2
```

Without the elast.properties file and the second bean content (i.e. from count to the minutesTime section in yaml) I see the yml is loading and I am running it with :

```
java -jar elast-search-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=ere.yml
```

I am running multiple properties file because I want to have a default configuration as well and the module is still evolving. I have `@Autowired` the class in the spring boot application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "log")
public class LogRule {

    private int count;
    private String searchText;
    private String[] services;
    private int minutesTime;
}
```

> 1. I want to read all YAML configuration as a list.
> 2. I want to read the configuration file if the file is changed or at regular intervals.

Comment: Remove `.properties` and `.yml` from `spring.config.name`. Spring Boot will suffix with `.properties`, `.xml` and `.yml` automatically including the profile specific version of that. Assuming you are using Spring Boot 2.x use `spring.config.additional-location` instead of `spring.config.location` to prevent you from overwriting the default. also you might want to include `application` in the `spring.config.name` as well.

Comment: It is able to read the YAML file now thanks for that. But do you see any changes needed for YAML itself ? In YAMLLint.com I see the second instance is retained and the rest are removed so I assume YAML syntax is wrong somewhere ...

Comment: That isn't so much the YAML as well the structure you are using, there will be a single `LogRule` and thus the last one will be retained.

Comment: So how can I add multiple beans to a list then ?

Comment: You have to create a wrapper which contains them and change your yaml accordingly.